# Visual Basic 6vDatareport "Report Width is larger than paper width" error

Tags: mysql, vb6

I've 8 fields to put in the paper. I'm really having a hard time solving this problem..

Is it possible to make the paper into landscape without getting the error??

Can anyone help?? I already tried changing the reportwidth and width in the properties.. but I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The error means just that: [the report is too wide for your printer settings](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/197915). You can set the report's orientation to Landscape after you have updated your VB6 IDE to [service pack 6](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5721)

Comment: how do that?? i mean i'll change it to Landscape in the Paper Size??

Comment: @user1130195 The DataReport has a property called Orientation. You can set this to Landscape. If you do not see the property install Servicepack 6 for VB6.